# How to use pip with Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have python 3.6 installed, I have a python extension installed on Visual Studio code but I still can't use pip on Visual Studio code. It says it is not a recognised command. Any help please?

Update: I tried installing pip manually but a file in `python2.7` keeps stopping. What's bothersome is that I uninstalled python 2.7 ages ago and I've currently removed every folder with it but `python-V` still says I have `python2.7.6` installed.

I'm on windows 10

Comment: You dont specify which OS you are on, but if you are on Windows, see what the Path values for Python is . If it points to Python 2.7 location , please replace it with the folder that points to your current installation..

Comment: Here is a SO link that might help you , if you are on windows : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: I already checked the path, there isn't anything with python is it. Is that a problem? Also I'm on windows sorry, I'll specify it now

Comment: I am pretty sure if you add your ( Python 3.6 installation ) location to the system path it should be resolved.

Comment: @Gagan okay, I'll do that now. Thank you

Comment: You might want to restart VS code after having changed the path.

Comment: So I changed the path and now VS Code is using python3.6 which is great but it still doesn't recognise pip as a command and my Bash Shell is still using the python 2.7.6 version

Comment: have you tried running pip from outside of vscocde using 3.6 ?

Comment: I was going to use my bash shell but it's still using the uninstalled version of python2.6.7.

Comment: Okay. I got the VScode to use pip by adding the pip path to PATH. I'll fix the bash shell later I guess. Thank you for the help

Comment: If i create a new answer , would you be kind enough to accept that as an answer .. it would be helpful ! - thanks

Comment: Thanks :)  .. much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure your problems of VSCode not finding the correct version of Python  will be resolved  if you add your ( Python 3.6 installation ) location to the system path.

Comment: How would you do that for macOS?

Comment: I found pip in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Scripts-folder, and needed to add this to the windows path.

Comment: @MortenNørgaard he asked about OSX, why you giving windows path?

Comment: @holms I was adding to Gagan's answer, not responding to CyberMew.

Answer (score 11):

I found some solution on this website:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

If you use Visual Studio Code, you can type the following command:

```
   C:\> py -m pip
```

If everything is alright, you should see the list of commands, which you can use. They are listed in your terminal, as per below.

[image]

I also would advise you to check/select the version of Python you are using:

[VSCode: There is no Pip installer available in the selected environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993566/vscode-there-is-no-pip-installer-available-in-the-selected-environment)

Comment: I got a "C:\ : The term 'C:\' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again." error running this command

Comment: Make sure that your path is written correctly. It's good to copy a sample path from another Python console and change the directory. Your comment states, that the path hasn't been written correctly. It might be even one letter wrong and the following error will appear.

Comment: I copied the command from your answer directly

Comment: Have you installed the Python plugin for VSC?

Comment: Of course, I need to install a package for a python project but pip install isn't working

Comment: I'm an idiot, I got it. I put down "C:\> py" instead of putting down C:\ then the path to my python

Comment: @SomeGuy don't call yourself this way! You wouldn't want to know how many silly mistakes I did. We are learning and getting better every day! Glad, that I could help you :)