# VSCode: There is no Pip installer available in the selected environment

Tags: python, pip, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run the autopep8 linter on a Python file in VSCode.

I've followed the instructions here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments and selected my interpreter (⇧⌘P): `/usr/local/bin/python`

I then try to format my code, and VSCode says autopep8 isn't installed, and can be installed via Pip. However, when I try to install via Pip, it says `There is no Pip installer available in the selected environment`.

I then tried launching a terminal in the current environment by selecting **Python: Create Terminal** from the Command Palette.

The terminal opens fine, `pip` is present, and I'm even able to `pip install autopep8` in the terminal that opened in VSCode, but when I try running the **Format Document** command I get the same errors that `autopep8` and `pip` aren't available in the environment.

Comment: What platform are you on, what Python are you using, and how did you install it? If you're on Linux, you may have installed a distro Python package that splits pip out into a separate package, like `python-pip`, in which case you need to install that. If you're on macOS, you may be using Apple's pre-installed Python, which doesn't come with pip (in which case you really should install a separate Python instead, but if you really want to, you can install pip for that one). And so on.

Comment: Or, if you're just using a really old version of Python (before 2.7.9, or 3.0-3.3), it just didn't come with `pip` back then. In that case, if you can't upgrade to a newer Python (and you're not using a linux distro-installed Python), you need to use [`get-pip.py`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

Comment: I'm on Mac OS X, latest version, and I'm using a Python 3.6 installed via Homebrew that definitely has pip. I can even access pip from inside the terminal I can spin up inside VSCode.

I was able to update my User Settings to get it to work:

```
    "python.formatting.autopep8Path": "/usr/local/bin/autopep8",
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "/usr/local/bin/pylint"
}
```

but I'm not a huge fan of that...

Comment: Does installing Python 3.6 with Homebrew really create a `/usr/local/bin/python` rather than just `/usr/local/bin/python3`? (It didn't used to back when they had separate python2 and python3 packages, but I haven't used it recently.)

Comment: More importantly (because that last question probably won't turn out to help…), please edit the information about platform, etc., into your question, rather than just putting it in a comment. And also, just to make sure: when you do the "select environment" thing, I assume VSCode properly labels it as something like "Python 3.6 (64-bit) Python Software Foundation", not just the label it uses when it's confused about the interpreter version, right?

Comment: Also, make sure the same label appears in the status bar, and maybe double-check the workspace settings.json to make sure they got set correctly. And is there a python.envFile with anything weird in it? Finally, Could you switch to using virtual environments, or even pipenv, or would any suggestions in that direction be inappropriate?

Comment: it may be best to use virtual environment.  Then activate the environment and run pip and other commands while the virtual environment is activated.

Answer (score 120):

On Ubuntu16.04, I worked with Python3 in vscode and

```
apt-get install python3-pip
```

solves my problem.

That's because I discover that: Under my terminal, I type the `pip -V`. It displays it's for Python2, not for Python3.

Comment: Make sure you add `sudo` to the command. That is `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` This worked for me.

Comment: howdy - many thanks for the hint.  Can i install VSCode with this command on a endeavourOS too!?

Answer (score 98):

Man you can only change the interpreter.

Go in (ctrl + shift + p), then type Python: Select Interpreter, this way you choose the version that your extension needs.

This worked for me.

Comment: Worked. So the issue is, after creating an env for a project, it is must to select the interpreter for that env. Otherwise, installler does not start automatically.

Comment: That's the right solution to the problem. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: many thanks for the hint.  want to install VSCode on a endeavourOS too!?

Comment: On mac it's clover + shift + p

Answer (score 61):

I have multiple python versions:

```
2.7
3.6
3.7
```

1. Tell the vscode/ visual studio code, which version to use:

press the following (Show All Commands):   **`Ctrl + Shift + P`**
paste the following:   **`Python: Select Interpreter`**
Select one of the version that it shows, I have selected **`python 3.7.3 64-bit`**

2. Update python path in settings:

press **`Ctrl + ,`** to open Settings
search for **`python.pythonPath`**
change **`python`** to **`/usr/bin/python3.7`**

**Note**: this may not be needed, however, make sure `/usr/bin/python3.7` really exists for you, you may have at a different path like `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`, etc.

3. I had pip but it was 2.7, but since I am choosing python 3, it's pip needs to be installed

Run the following command in Terminal:  **`apt-get install python3-pip`**

4. Restart vscode

With the above steps, all issues got resolved. Hope that helps.

Comment: This works for windows too. Used the following path C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python37_64

Comment: @Rey Happy to it worked almost as-is. You comment is great help for Windows users.

Answer (score 12):

try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
then type

```
Python: Select Interpreter
```

and select the python version.

Answer (score 11):

Installing python3-pip fixed the issue for me.

```
apt-get install python3-pip
```

Comment: Hi Rafik  want to install VSCode on a endeavourOS too!?

Answer (score 6):

1.Select the File > Preferences > Settings command (⌘,) to open your User Settings.

2.Search and Create or modify an entry for python.pythonPath with the full path to the Python executable according to your requirements.For Example i changed it to python2.6 path to this path /usr/local/bin/python3.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem today, none of the solutions helped me. Eventually, I figured it out myself.

I'm posting this answer for people who are having this problem. Just go to your ./venv folder and you will find a .cfg file.

Just make sure **include-system-site-packages** is set to **true**

```
home = /usr/bin
include-system-site-packages = true
version = 3.8.5
```

If it still doesn't work, just run `sudo install python3-pip` once in the terminal. Of course you could always change the version here as well.

Answer (score 4):

(on mac)if you are using python3 but vscode told you pip was not installed , you could change python version on vscode bottom.
And I guess you are using another terminal but not bash , vscode's default terminal is bash. Bash don't know you have install pip@2.

Comment: As of VSCode Version: 1.49.1, the official terminal is `zsh`

Answer (score 3):

For WSL users:

If you have your work files in linux subsystem path, you still need pip for windows in order to VSCode to use it.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20 running under WSL 2, and installing `python 3` inside Ubuntu fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu:

Make sure, that you have Python and pip installed.

Go to Settings, type python.py in search input. This should find Python Path settings.

Remove this path (if it is currently setted), save. Exit Code and set this to current value.

For me is /usr/bin/python3

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue when trying use autopep8.  For me - it had nothing to do with pip (I know it is installed) but the path the VScode python extension was using.

If you open up the extension and go to it's setting and scroll down, there is a path you can designate for autopep8:  Python › Formatting: Autopep8 Path

I used the path recommended by these docs:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting

Which was: python.formatting.autopep8Args

I stopped getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is a solution for Windows.

1. First make Sure your Python is installed properly. Run the following command:

```
py --version
```

2. If the Previous command is running fine it will give you your python version. In that case go ahead and check if pip is present or not. Run the below command to check:

```
py -m pip
```

3. If pip is present in your system it show give you a list of option and info. If that's the case then go Ahead and run pip. All you need to do is precede the command you would normally write with py -m. For example:

```
pip install flask 

py -m pip install flask
```

4. This should solve your problem.

Comment: It's worked for me, but can you explain why window use `py`? Another my Window PC use `python`

Comment: @ToanNguyenPhuoc<br/>`py` is itself located in C:\Windows (which is always part of the PATH), which is why you find it. When you installed Python, you didn't check the box to add it to your PATH, which is why it isn't there. In general, it's best to use the Windows Python Launcher, py.exe anyway, so this is no big deal. Just use `py` for launching consistently, and stuff will just work.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows system check the environment variable>System variables 
check the Path variable for the python path.(if not found set the path variable for python)

Copy the path and paste under  vscode>file>preferences>settings>python.pythonPath

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem while learning django and the terminal would not let me pip install anything.

Create a virtual environment in shell and then use the path of the environment as your interpreter. This worked for me.

> Note: You might want to create to create the environment in a different shell altogether and then upload the folder of the environment into vscode.
> Then you open up the settings file in the environment folder.

This image will hopefully give you a good idea. [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWN4B.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem with pylint in a docker container. I realized that the reason the VS-Code-prompted pylint install didn't work for me was because I was using the global python installation (global inside my docker container, anyway), which can require elevated permissions to install things and VS code wasn't running as root in the container. According to [the vs code python extension docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_enable-linters):

> Note: If you're using a global environment and VS Code is not running elevated, linter installation may fail. In that case, either run VS Code elevated, or manually run the Python package manager to install the linter at an elevated command prompt for the same environment: for example sudo pip3 install pylint (macOS/Linux) or pip install pylint (Windows, at an elevated prompt)

Answer (score 0):

Go in (ctrl + shift + p), then type Python: Select Interpreter,
then type  Python: Select Interpreter and then click on "Enter interpreter path"
Then click on "Find.. Browse your file. "
Then type Python in c drive search bar and click on latest version of python in case if you have multiple version of python. Enter and modify wait for sometimes to complete then close.
After that restart your vs code.
It worked for me it will work for you also.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error with poetry environment. `poetry self update` did the work