# How to install a new python module on VSCode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-module

I'm trying to install new python modules on my computer and I know how to install through the terminal, but I wish to know if there is a way to install a new module directly through VSCode (like it is possible on PyCharm)?

I already installed through the terminal, it isn't a problem, but I want to install without be obligate to open the terminal when I'm working on VSCode.

Comment: The [Getting Started with Python in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) page says to "use the Command Palette to run **Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal**". Probably not the news you wanted to hear.

Answer (score 12):

You should open the terminal inside the VSCode and install the modules you want.
something like

[image: VSCode Snapshot]

if that's not you meant, please let me know.

Comment: I've tried to do it but I'm getting an error about the pip version. I'm using a venv for my python projects and on the terminal, my pip version is updated but it isn't on VSCode what is very strange because I'm using this venv as an interpreter on VSCode. Seems to me that the VSCode isn't recognizing the changes I make on venv through the terminal.

Comment: @TCrepalde what error are you getting? Your question didn't mention a failure in the terminal, just that you wanted a GUI way to do package installs (for which there isn't one by design as VS Code doesn't like doing things via the GUI if it's reasonable to do from the terminal).

Comment: @BrettCannon I found out about the problem with the terminal after I post this question... I'm starting with vscode now so it's some problems that I can't identify instantly. My issue now is with the vscode terminal /:

Comment: Just for the record, I solved the problem with the vscode terminal by editing the json configurations! I forced the vscode terminal to point to the terminal of the system, so now I can install packages right from the vscode. :)

Comment: I receive the information that 'pip' is not found as a name of cmdlet, a function, a script or an executible programm. I shall check the writing of the name.

Comment: @Ben if I understood your problem, I think this question can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command#:~:text=You%20need%20to%20add%20the,added%20to%20your%20PATH%20variable.

Comment: this question has some answers :) Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

1. First of all I would advise you to select the current Python version you have. It has been explained here:

[VSCode: There is no Pip installer available in the selected environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993566/vscode-there-is-no-pip-installer-available-in-the-selected-environment)

2. Next, you should check is the pip installed in your Python main directory or not, by checking how to do on this website:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

or this thread

[How to use pip with Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463866/how-to-use-pip-with-visual-studio-code/67517618#67517618)

by typing

```
   py -m pip
```

in your terminal, like

```
   C:\Users\m\Desktop\Python> py -m pip
```

You should have the list of commands and general options which can be used. One of them is `install`

On the Python library platform, you always have the command to be copied in order to the installation of package you want.

[image]

4. In your terminal, the initial command should look as:

   ```
      PS C:\Users\m\Desktop\Python> py -m
   ```

to which you should append the command prepared on the Python library platform (by copying it and pasting).

```
   C:\Users\m\Desktop\Python> py -m pip install openpyxl
```

That's it. The package should be installed in your Python folder, what you will see in the terminal.

5. If everything is alright, you just need to type

   ```
   import openpyxl     #or other package name, which you downloaded
   ```

and use it!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately! for now, only possible way is terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Installing using the 'pip' from within python worked for me.

1. On the vscode terminal type in python and goto the python prompt
2. At python prompt:

   import pip

   pip.main(['install', "pandas"]) #this will install pandas in the current environment.
3. quit python prompt and return to vscode terminal.