# Python modules in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How to download python modules in visual studio code?
I have tried to download using pip but vs-code uses windows cmd/PowerShell therefore pip didn't work.

Comment: "but vs-code uses windows cmd/PowerShell therefore pip didn't work" that is not true

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so how do I do?

Comment: vs-code simply opens a terminal console for your convenience. What terminal is totally up to the operating system you are using. Aside from that, pip works also on cmd. Please refer to these step: https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html and if you get stuck try to update your question with more details relevant to the specific step in which errors occur.

Comment: See [How to use pip with Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42463866/2745495)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best solution is to create a virtual environment for your project and then install into that. So if you're on Windows and don't have access to `pip` then you probably used the python.org installer and don't have `python3` on your path either. In that case you can do `py -m venv .venv` to create a virtual environment (this is assuming you're using Python 3). Once that's created you will want to select the virtual environment (see the [environments documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) on how to do that).

That gets you a proper environment to develop in. From there you can open a terminal with `Python: Create Terminal` and that will automatically activate the virtual environment, putting `python` on your path so you can use `python -m pip install` to install your dependencies (`pip` will also be there, but it's better to use `python -m pip` to help make sure you're  installing into the Python interpreter you expect).