# Pip not installing at all

Tags: python, pip, installation, package-managers

I am using VS code and I have been trying for two hours now. Technically I should have Pip preinstalled as I'm using 3.8.2, although when I tried downloading and installing it (from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) nothing is there and nothing will come up when i type pip help/pip --version in cmd and when i do any pip install . It's not installing. Any help?

Comment: Make sure that, you haven't install it in Virtual environment. Plus here is a guide for installation of PIP https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/, and if you using Linux OS, just type `sudo apt install python3-pip` in terminal

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463866/how-to-use-pip-with-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner, but I would suggest uninstalling python completely, and installing it again.

Comment: I completely uninstalled python and reinstalled automatically. I then uninstalled and installed all my vs-code extensions.When i type anything with pip it just says something like 'the term 'pip' is not recognised'.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research you might one of these useful:

PIP installation is not added to the system variable – In order to be able to run Python commands from a CMD window, you will need to add the path of your PiP installation to your PATH in the system variable. If you installed Python using the installation executable, it should be added automatically.

The installation is incorrectly added in your PATH – It’s easy to mess up the PATH if you add it manually. Additional space or the missing of a semicolon before the new PATH will end up producing the error.