# No module named 'telethon.sync'; 'telethon' is not a package

Tags: python, telethon

Hi, I want to use the telethon package.
I installed it and called it in CMD and it works fine
but when i called it from VSCODE this is not worked And shows this error:
 `No module named 'telethon.sync'; 'telethon' is not a package`

what is the problem?!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you using any virtual environment? Please also add the actual code as text which is giving the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

VSCODE doesn't use pip by default, that sounds like what your issue is

I imagine your CMD python installation is different to the one VSCODE is looking at

Try adding your python installation to your system path

I found this information from a quick look at a similarly named visual studio related python issue

There might be some other useful information there

[How to use pip with Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463866/how-to-use-pip-with-visual-studio-code)