# Why can I install modules, but not import them? - Python

Tags: python, pip

I can install modules, such as the 'requests' module. However, if I try and import them, python tells me it's missing. I can use native modules such as the json module, however.

I tried to install and import third-party modules in python on visualstudio code, but I'm stuck trying to figure out how to import them.

Comment: I should have specified earlier: I get the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'third_party_module_name_here'" error

Comment: Most likely, either you're installing them for the wrong Python, or you're importing the wrong name. We can't tell.

Comment: If you are on Mac or Linux, what is the output of `which python` and `whereis python`? I guess it's probably due to the virtual env stuff that is mis-configured.

Answer (score 0):

the only reason I see is you are installing the modules in different path and python is not able to refer for import script.
Try below for installing the module and it may help

[How to use pip with Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463866/how-to-use-pip-with-visual-studio-code/67517618#67517618)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you responses guys.
Now that I know what the issue is, thanks to you guys, I learned about path and how to add python to path, following this guide: https://www.maketecheasier.com/what-is-the-windows-path/
I can now successfully install third party packages and have them be recognised in VSCode :)